# Can't perform a Factory reset or reboot my Alienware R3 15" (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, bootloader

I have an Alienware R3 15" that I tried to factory reset directly without a USB-windows-image (at first), here are the steps that I followed :

1. I had an Ubuntu partition (on dual boot) on this pc so I followed [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/) to remove it. Note that I don't have exactly the same partitions as I have an additional HDD & SSD...
2. I then rebooted and got the message (in french) : "Windows n'a pas pu terminer l'installation. Pour installer Windows sur cet ordinateur, redémarre le programme d'installation", which translates to "Windows could not finish the installation. To install windows on this computer, reboot the installation program".

Since this didn't work, I went and applied these steps :

1. Next I went to the dell (From another pc) support & downloaded the utility to burn an image on a USB.
2. Booted windows from the USB using F12, did a system reset by deleting all user files...
3. System reset finished and I still get the message: "Windows could not finish the installation. To install windows on this computer, reboot the installation program".

I think I messed up something during the selection of primary & secondary boot because I can still see the "Ubuntu" as the secondary boot even if the partition no longer exists.

Here are all the boot options (in order):

UEFI OPTIONS:

1. Windows boot manager
2. Ubuntu
3. Onboard NIC (IPV4)
4. Onboard NIC (IPV6)
5. USB1 - UEFI OS(SanDisk)
6. HDD2 - Windows Boot Manager (Samsung SSD CM871 M.2 2280 128FB)

OTHER OPTIONS:

1. BIOS Setup
2. Diagnostics
3. Peripheral Device Setting (OPROM Setting) [This one is greyed out]
4. Change Boot Mode Setting
5. BIOS Flash Update

Could you please help me figure out how to factory reset my computer?
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea which Dell utility you used by you should have simply used the Media Creation Tool.  Is your goal to keep your personal files or cleanly reinstall Windows?  Your actions have likely deleted your personal files, so you should simply delete the partitions, and install Windows using the installation media that is created by the Media Creation Tool.

Comment: I am using the "Media Creation Tool" utility

Comment: It was on purpose that I deleted my user files

Comment: Media Creation Tool is from Microsoft or Dell

Comment: Sorry, actually the Dell utility I used is called SupportAssist OS Recovery, it installs stuff needed for Alienware functioning like lights extra buttons etc....

I enter my serial number and they give me the software https://www.dell.com/support/home/fr-fr/drivers/osiso/recoverytool/wt64a

Comment: Perhaps it also activates the uses the genuine windows version that came with the pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I finally got my pc to work and was able to format it.

As a side-note, whatever you do, don't turn your boot mode to legacy within the BIOS, because your pc won't be able to turn on anymore and you'll have to reset the bios manually by disassembling the pc and taking out the CMOS... I digress.

This answer is specifically for dell users as I said in the comments above, the factory reset can (and should) only be done using dell's utility software because they identify the computer's serial number and serve the software with windows genuine software key.

1. Download the software via dell's support, I used the following [link](https://www.dell.com/support/home/fr-fr/drivers/osiso/recoverytool/wt64a) but make sure you find the right link, from the website relevant to where you made your purchase.
2. Put it in an adequate USB
3. Disconnect every "extra" hard drive or SSD or RAM you put yourself on the pc as they seem to interfere with the factory reset. (By opening your pc and removing the said components). Keep only the original stuff the computer came with.
4. Restart your pc and press F12 or F2 to select the USB as a boot option.
5. Make sure you have an internet connection as you need to "Factory Reset and download the updates" and not just "factory reset".
6. Follow through the procedure
7. When your pc is up and running install additional updates.

These are the steps that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have a boot media for Windows 10 that was created
by the Media Creation Tool.

In that case, doing a reset to the disk is simple: Boot with it
and do the installation. When you arrive at the disk selection step,
select the disk and quick-format it, so it becomes totally Unallocated.

Now select the disk and install Windows. It will allocate the
required partitions and install itself.

Comment: But that's the thing, I don't get prompted to choose a hard drive. I think this is maybe why the installation isn't successful?

Comment: Boot into the BIOS and verify that it can indeed see the disk. You might also try to reset the BIOS.

Comment: I did reset the bios "physically" by unplugging the CMOS battery for a while

Comment: The medias I see are : 
- `Acspi (PNP0a03,0)/Pci(14|0)/Usb(0,0)/HD(Part1, Sige<some_serial_number>)`
- `Acspi (PNP0a03,0)/Pci(17|0)/Sata(1,0)/HD(Part1, Sige<some_serial_number>)`
- `Acspi (PNP0a03,0)/Pci(17|0)/Sata(10,0)/HD(Part1, Sige<some_serial_number>)`

Comment: This doesn't tell me much. Verify what you are doing against the article [How to Clean Install Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-clean-install-windows-10-a.html) and tell me at which step the process stops for you.

Comment: Alright, what I'll do is disconnect the secondary SSD & the HDD and keep just the OS SSD and try and perform a reset according to the link you sent me, but I don't have "Media Creation Tool", like I said in a comment above, I try to use Dell's utility tool for install & recovery since the OS is customized a bit by dell.

Comment: I don't know the Dell utility, but your above procedure looks good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126387/discussion-between-aetos-and-harrymc).